# Not able to show the canlendar pop up on second row in my grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am having 5 rows in my gird with EffectiveDate texbox but on click on textbox showing popup calendar working for first row.

Not for remaing rows when I click on my any other row except first row its not showing me up the popup calendar window. is that something I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

> Each id value must be used only once
>   within a document. If more than one
>   element has been assigned the same ID,
>   queries that use that ID will only
>   select the first matched element in
>   the DOM.

You're using the same ID for the text box in each row.  Try generating a unique ID for each row.  You may also want to assign a class to the text box and use a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to select them all.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multiple rows with the same ID? This will cause problems like what you have described. You need to have unique id's.